# Angular 5 Ngrx State lost during browser page refresh

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, state, ngrx

I am new to angular 5 and Ngrx, some how i managed to implement a login functionality, once login is success i am taking the user to dashboard. But if I refresh the page the user state seems to be lost. How to make the user state persistent even the page reloads ?

Comment: NGRX state is only held in memory. If you want it to persist between page refreshes, you may want to look at storing some of that state in `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`, and trying to load it from there on page load

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How to make the user state persistent even the page reloads?

as @user184994 Mentioned `NGRX` state is only held in memory. If you want it to persist between page refreshes Go for `LocalStorage` or `sessionStorage`

`localStorage` and `sessionStorage` accomplish the exact same thing and have the same API, but with `sessionStorage` the data is persisted only until the window or tab is closed, while with `localStorage` the data is persisted until the user manually clears the browser cache or until your web app clears the data.

I would suggest you to go for [**@ngx-pwa/local-storage**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage) Async local storage for Angular

## For Angular 5:

```
npm install @ngx-pwa/local-storage@5
```

**Register it in your RootModule**

```
import { LocalStorageModule } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LocalStorageModule,
    ...
  ]
```

**Inject and use it**

```
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

@Injectable()
export class YourService {

  constructor(protected localStorage: LocalStorage) {}

}
```

**Usage**

```
let user: User = { firstName: 'Henri', lastName: 'Bergson' };

this.localStorage.setItem('user', user).subscribe(() => {});
```

Answer (score 2):

local-storage and sessions-storage introduce security risks (user info can be manipulated) and I think there is a better answer to how to address the underlying issue of how to survive a browser refresh.

In general, you're probably better off putting some code into the app component's onInit method to reload data that needs to survive a browser refresh.

Comment: As long as you are careful about what you put in local storage and session storage, everything should be fine. Let's say if you store your authentication token which shouldn't be visible to anyone you are doomed already whether it's redux state or any other storage which lives on browser.

Comment: Sarora's answer supported what I was thinking, but then @SerdarSayın comment made me confuse. 
So what exactly goes into browser storage and what not?

Comment: As i stated  "if you store your authentication token which shouldn't be visible to anyone" something like a secret key. Check out this https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04 for further information.

Comment: @KishorPawar - a lot depends on your app and security concerns here. If you're just storing random application data and don't care about security, and don't want to store things on the backend perhaps (e.g. some in browser game), then localstorage can be a useful place to put data. For a business app, however, you generally want everything persisted in the db, and you might only use local or session storage for holding a temporary authentication token, for example. To have the app remember the application state (e.g. user's profile info) you can load it on init to survive a page refresh.

Comment: @sarora exactly what I had thought,