# how to persist data when navigate to another url by Angular router

Tags: angular, angular-router

How to save data when I navigate to another route? For example, I have routes as below. I navigate to routerA and input some data. If I navigate to routerB and then navigate back to routeA  I won't see the previous data that I input.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'routerA', component: RouterAComponent },
  { path: 'routerB', component: RouterBComponent }
]
```

Comment: You can use `Localstorage`

Comment: Have a Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50428436/5695162) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50609666/5695162)

Comment: if you want to save data even if you reload the page use local storage, else juste use a service (provided in common module)

Answer (score 1):

you should use service for store data in variable and access this data through service.

```
.....
    @Injectable()
    export class UserService {

      public username;
      MPIDList: any;
      days: any;
      uid: String;
      BackUrl: any;
      activeMPID: String;
      LastExecutionDate: String;

....
```