# Event emitter changes are disapperaring after page reload

Tags: javascript, angular

This is my header component ,which contains a cart icon plus an anchor tag to empty the cart .I show the anchor tag only when the cart has products.
headecomponent.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';
import { MessageService } from '../message.service';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  flag=false;
  subscription:any;
  //totalproducts:number;
  constructor(public appservice:AppService,private msg:MessageService,private ss: SharedService) {
    this.subscription = this.ss.getEmittedValue()
      .subscribe(

       ()=>{
         this.changeflag();
       }

      );

   }
  //totalproducts= this.appservice.gettotalproducts();
  //this function removes cart products and relaod the page
  emptycart(){
   this.appservice.removeall();
    location.reload();
    this.flag=false;
  }
  changeflag(){
    this.flag=true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

   //this.appservice.removecarttoken();
   //this hows the empty red one if cart gets filled


  }


}
```

And this is my product component where i add product and call shared service that emits event such that it is subscribed in above component and it changes the flag

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../models/product.model';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit  {
  products :Product[]=[
{id:"xy1",name:"SSR-3000-15-POS-TERMINAL",picture:"a.jpg",price:1375,category:"screentills"},
{id:"xy2",name:"SSR-T86E SCALE",picture:"b.jpg",price:1,category:"cashregister"},
{id:"xy3",name:"SSR-300-RECEIPT-PRINTERS",picture:"c.jpg",price:451,category:"printers"},
{id:"xy5",name:"EPSON-DOT-MATRIX-PRINTER",picture:"d.jpg",price:560,category:"kitchenprinter"},
{id:"xy6",name:"CD-24 – Heavy duty cash drawer 24v",picture:"h.jpg",price:198.00,category:"cashdrawers"},
{id:"xy7",name:"Portable Data Terminal",picture:"i.jpg",price:550.00,category:"barcodescanner"},
{id:"xy8",name:"Magstripe Card Reader",picture:"h.jpg",price:120.00,category:"accessories"},
{id:"xy9",name:"SSR-C86H 2017 – 15″ Touch screen Cash Register with Software – 2017 model",picture:"e.jpg",price:1560.00,category:"cashregister"},
{id:"xy10",name:"SSR-C86H – 15″ Touch screen Cash Register with Software",picture:"e.jpg",price:1460.00,category:"cashregister"},
{id:"xy11",name:"SSR-86E 2017 – 12″ Touch screen Cash Register with Software – 2017 model",picture:"f.jpg",price:1280.00,category:"cashregister"},
{id:"xy12",name:"SSR-86E – 12″ Touch screen Cash Register with Software",picture:"f.jpg",price:1180.00,category:"cashregister"},
{id:"xy13",name:"SSR-250 Receipt Printers",picture:"g.jpg",price:385.00,category:"printers"},
{id:"xy14",name:"Omni-352 (Omni Directional Scanner)",picture:"j.jpg",price:330.00,category:"barcodescanner"},
{id:"xy15",name:"SSR-10.4 – 10.4″ Secondary Screen",picture:"k.jpg",price:440.00,category:"accessories"},
{id:"xy16",name:"SSR-8.4 – 8.4″ Secondary Screen",picture:"m.jpg",price:330.00,category:"accessories"},
{id:"xy17",name:"VFD-890 (VFD Customer Display)",picture:"l.jpg",price:160.00,category:"accessories"},

  ];
  //
  //dependency injection of appservice
  constructor(private appservice:AppService,private ss: SharedService) { }

  addproduct(product){

    //the method return true if success;
   this.appservice.addtocart(product,1)
    alert("Product added to the cart");
    this.ss.change();//emiiting event
   }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.appservice.removecarttoken();

  }
}
```

This is my shared service

```
import { Component, Injectable,Input,Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
//this is for removing empty when cart is empty
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
  @Output() fire: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {
    console.log('shared service started');
  }

  change() {
   console.log('change started'); 
    this.fire.emit(true);
  }

  getEmittedValue() {
    return this.fire;
  }
}
```

It works fine ,no issues but when I reload the page the anchor tag becomes invisible again ,how to make these changes last even after page refresh???

This is my header.component.html

```
        <a routerLink="/cart">
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span id="checkout_items" class="checkout_items">{{appservice.gettotalproducts()}}</span>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li *ngIf="this.flag"><a  href="#" style="margin-left:8px; color:red"(click)="emptycart()" >empty</a></li>
```

any idea how to achieve it?? Well i have tried calling subscribe in ngOnit too but no success.

Comment: just to make sure, your anchor tag is visible if this.flag === true?

Comment: yes right ,it should be visible when flag is true

Comment: Your entire application will have its state reset when the page refreshes, resetting to its default state. You'll need to look into storing your checkout items/flag setting somewhere so it can persist between application loads.

Answer (score 1):

To persist data between page refreshes you can use localStorage or sessionStorage https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp.

See this question, in which there is a suggested package to work with localStorage [Angular 5 Ngrx State lost during browser page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428320/angular-5-ngrx-state-lost-during-browser-page-refresh)