# Angular how to get previous view data on click of browser back button from another view

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript

I am trying to create multiple view in my angular application by using routing, once navigate to another view on click of browser back button not able to get previous view data (page is getting refreshed completely)

Comment: Either use a singleton service to persist data or you can go for Local Storage

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: https://alligator.io/js/introduction-localstorage-sessionstorage/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428320/angular-5-ngrx-state-lost-during-browser-page-refresh/50428436#50428436

Answer (score 0):

Each page should be able to get all needed data by itself (resolvers, onInit). Because we should also be able to handle `refresh` of a page. In some case it could be a good idea to [cache BE response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-http-network-call-in-r) (services).